# Perform both the normal click and long click at button

Tags: android, button

I have a single button named as CheckIn.Have a look at my code.

```
    checkIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

       Toast.makeText(HomeSafeActivity.this, "Normal Press", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    });


    checkIn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(HomeSafeActivity.this, "Long press", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();



            return false;
        }
    });
```

Now when i normal press the button the message shows as Normal press.When i Long press the button the message shows as long press as well as Normal press both. What i want that when i long press the button only long press event should triggered not the normal press event.How can i achieve this??

Comment: Disable onClickListener() inside onLongClickListener().  That could be one option.  I'm not sure if it works, just firing ideas :)

Comment: I think @ClaireG is right. Try with that solution.

Comment: Put a flag in both the functions `onClick` and `onLongClick`, to mutually exclude each other (via an `if` statement). You can't uncatch one of the two events, in case you have both the listeners.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I got the solution of my Question.Return the true instead of false.Just see below:-

```
    checkIn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

            Toast.makeText(HomeSafeActivity.this, "Long preess", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            return true;
        }
    });
```

Comment: thanks for the onLongClick method... it helped me a lot :D

Answer (score 17):

`onLongClick()` - This returns a boolean to indicate whether you have consumed the event and it should not be carried further. That is, `return true` to indicate that you have handled the event and it should stop here; `return false` if you have not handled it and/or the event should continue to any other `on-click listeners`.

Comment: This is a good idea; however, what if there was something else instead of a `Toast`?

Comment: Actually i just define the Toast in my activity as an example.I am using the startActivity instead of Toast and both the events are triggered

Comment: A long click is also considered as a click, that's why both the functions are called.

Answer (score 9):

You should return true in the event of long click

**Example:**

```
  btnBookingMasterCab.setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            if(preCheckoutInfo!=null){
                rlChooseCard.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

public boolean onLongClick(View v) is boolean returns true if it is clicked
so make return true;

Answer (score 2):

Here's one solution (this will work if (when both are triggered), first the long press gets triggered, then the normal press):

```
int clickFlag = 0;
checkIn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

  @Override
  public void onClick(View v) {

    if(clickFlag != 2){
      Toast.makeText(HomeSafeActivity.this, "Normal Press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
      clickFlag = 0;
    }

  });

  checkIn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

      Toast.makeText(HomeSafeActivity.this, "Long press", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

      clickFlag = 2;
      return false;
    }
  });
}
```

Comment: just return true on a long click then you don't need a flag

Answer (score -1):

Try this; it should work.

```
checkIn.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {

    @Override
    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

        checkIn.setOnClickListener(null);

        Toast.makeText(HomeSafeActivity.this, "Long press", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score -3):

Try android:onclick="btnPressed" instead of OnClickListener and use OnLongClickListener is no problem in my testing code

Comment: How can you distinguish between long and short press then?

Comment: ya it's triggering only on onclick event occur,while button goesto long click it doesn't trigger.